# Is there a way to disable a cell from allowing input if another cell has data in it?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm basically trying to create a simple form on Google Sheets. I'd like to make it so that if a user inputs X into A2, then A3 will be *disabled*, otherwise A3 is open for input.

Is there a simple way to implement this? I'm currently just using conditional formatting to black out cells in an attempt to stray people from putting stuff in there, but it seems like a rather poor implementation if there's a way to actually disable a cell.

Comment: Already voted to migrate this to [webapps.se]. timoseewho, please don't simply repost this elsewhere; it should get migrated fairly quickly.

Comment: alright i'll give that a look thanks

Comment: @SightSpirit It's quite possible with data validation, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply to A3 data validation rule with the custom formula

```
=or(A2<>"X", isblank(A3))
```

It looks like this:

[image: data]

Comment: thank you very much! is <> the same thing as =?

Comment: No, it's exactly the opposite thing: "not equal". The validation condition says that valid input is "either A2 is not X, or A3 is blank". This translates logically into "If A2 is X, then A3 must be blank".

Comment: ahhh thanks hehe

i've actually run into a small problem now, basically i want A3 to do a number validation between 75-100 if A2's input is 'No', but disabled when A2's input is 'Yes'. is it possible to do.. 2 validations? lol

Comment: You can join multiple conditions using or and and. For example, this describes your situation: `=or(and(A2="Yes", isblank(A3)), and(A2="No", A3>=75, A3<=100))`  This says there are two valid situations, "Yes" &  blank A3, and "No" & number in [75,100] in A3

Comment: sigh

sorry to bother you again, i tried to do something similar with another cell here, `=or(and(B3="No",B4>=981,B4<=1199),and(B3="Yes",B4>=1318,B4<=1560))`. i want B4 to take the inputs between 981 and 1199 if B3 is "No", otherwise 1318 and 1560. i keep getting violation no matter what;\

Comment: wow okay i was just being stupid, i was checking the wrong cell haha, B4 instead of C4, thanks a lot man!

Comment: while i have you here, can i ask you something slightly related, but not really? is it possible to fill a dropdown list in cell A3 with A,B,C if cell A2 is "Yes", but fill it with X,Y,Z if a cell A2 is "No"? i guess like a dynamic dropdown based on the values of another cell

Comment: This is not a chat, and you don't have me here. Post a new question.

Comment: lol sorry, a bit new, don't quite know about the etiquette here

Comment: hey, i'm sorry to bring this up again, not sure if i'm supposed to start another post since this question is a bonus question to your solution. in the `=or(and(A2="Yes", isblank(A3)), and(A2="No", A3>=75, A3<=100))` code, is there a way to incorporate the 75->100 input into a dropdown instead of a regular user input? i personally fear this might not be possible since the formula itself is taking the place of where there'd normally be a dropdown (List of items) to set up;\