# Show data validation dropdown on cell if another cell isn't empty using custom formula

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to adapt [a few](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86757/is-it-possible-to-have-a-data-validation-with-a-custom-formula-with-a-dropdown-l) [other approaches](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-cell-from-allowing-input-if-another-cell-has-data-in) to this, but without much luck.

I want to create an approval dropdown. Each request could have up to five rows, but I want just a singular dropdown to display the Approval Status on the first line of the request. A mockup of what I'm thinking:

[image: mockup example]

In my example, I'd like to check A2 to see if it has any data. Then if it does, show the approval status data validation dropdown (in ColumnJ) with the options `Pending`, `Approved`, `Denied`. The problem I've run into is that if I use a custom formula in the data validation, it doesn't allow me to create a list of options in the dropdown (or create a list from a range) that would show the dropdown with the arrow, or at least I haven't found a formula that will allow me to do that.

Is this even possible, or are the list and custom formula criteria not compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a custom formula for validation never creates a dropdown. Dropdowns are available only for lists of values that are either entered directly into the validation rule, or are contained elsewhere in a sheet ("list from a range").

Possible workaround: use "list from a range" validation rule, referring to a range in which you use some formulas to compute the available options.

Example: cell B3 has validation rule saying "list from the range P3:R3". Cell P3 has the formula `=if(isblank(A3), "", {"aa", "bb", "cc"})`. So, if A3 is nonempty, than the range P3-R3 contains "aa", "bb", "cc", and these values appear in the dropdown in B3. Otherwise the range is blank, and so is the dropdown.

Comment: Why are there no dropdowns for custom formulas? There are formulas that create ranges such as FILTER and QUERY