# Add Data Validation to cell B if cell A has content?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like a dropdown to appear in each additional cell of a row if the first cell in the row has content. Is this possible?

*-- edited per request --*

If I enter the word "Cats" to cell A1, I'd like a Data Validation dropdown to appear in cell B1, with options "Kitten, Show Cat, Geriatric, Degenerate".

Comment: Welcome. I hope you will not take offence when I suggest that your question is ambiguous, lacking both clarity and detail. May I respectfully suggest that you develop and then share a spreadsheet (using test data) that articulates the scenario that you have sought to describe in your question. This will enable users to better understand the outcome that you are trying to achieve. Having said that, I am reasonably confident that the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks. I don't take any offense. You said you are reasonably confident "yes" is the answer to my ambiguous question, but I'll go ahead and try to give my question a little more substance. Edited above.

Comment: There are many (and I do mean, MANY) ways to manage dropdowns. But the answer in this topic[Show data validation dropdown on cell if another cell isn't empty using custom formula
](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112114/196152) is probably the least complicated that I have seen. In your case, the formula might be something like `=if(A1="Cat",{2,3,4},"")`